# Adding Background Image to FlowCover

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm using FlowCover in an app and need to add a background, but inserting a UIImageView and sending to the back in .xib only gives me the background image and buttons and no coverflow animation. I also cannot see where i would programme a

```
self.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc]initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bground.png"]];
```

type thing in the implemetation.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does appear that you can add an UIImageview to the ViewController's View in the MainWindow.nib:

[image]

In the editor dropdown you can send the image to the back. It means that the Flow Cover View MUST NOT be set to Opaque and then will sit on top of the ImageView.